# How to deploy VF Pages

Tags: visualforce

I've just deployes some classes and triggers from sandbox to production environment. 
I also wanted to deploy some VF Pages to production but I couldn't find the right way to do it, so I had to copy and paste them manually.

Can you help me about this? I'm sure there's some automated way to do this operation , and even if I reached my goal, I'd like to have some information about the best practices about VF pages deploying.

Thanks!

Comment: did you use changesets to deploy the classes/triggers - they can be used for VF pages as well? Or did you use eclipse or ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to deploy from a sandbox, use a change set, just as you would classes and triggers. Otherwise, you can use mavens mate, the force.com IDE, the migration tool, or an inmamaged package. You may also find more user friendly tools on the app exchange.